# What is the minimum separation for aircraft operating on or intersecting the same runway?

Tags: ground-operations, separation

How capturing of [this photo](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8543441) was ever possible:

[image]

<sub>(photo courtesy of [jetphotos.com](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8543441))</sub>

Shouldn't there be a bigger time / distance separation of three aircrafts using, operating or intersecting the same runway?

Shouldn't pictured situation be considered as a bit dangerous in terms of ground operations?

Comment: This is **not** a picture of a landing strip, it is a picture of a set of taxiways. These planes are simply taxiing (i.e. driving around on the ground at low speed, on their way between the runway and the gate)

Comment: @J.Hougaard Thanks for explaining me, what taxing is! :> I was aware of this, but it is always so nice if someone cares enough to explain words used.

Comment: Same location (intersection of taxiways N1 and N2), [more aircraft](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8407594). Runway 09-27 is on the left side. Airport [diagram](https://yinlei.org/x-plane10/jep/VABB.pdf) page 43.

Comment: If you see similar pictures in future, look at the color of the painted lines at the edge of the tarmac. Runway lines are white, taxiway lines are yellow. As you can see, the ones in your picture are all yellow, so the aircraft are on a taxiway, not a runway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As both aircraft are still on a taxiway, turning into two different intersections it's absolutely normal. Each intersection has a so called "holding point" where all aircraft must hold until a clearance to enter the runway is given.

In this particular situation the tower controller will ensure that only one aircraft enters the runway and waits until departure separation minima are given before clearing the second aircraft for takeoff.

In this way maximum efficiency is reached by using different intersections as the following aircraft can line up (and hold on the runway; only after receiving a clearance to do so of course) immediately behind the first aircraft.